# How can I optimize the performance of a slow-running query in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

I have a query that is taking over 30 seconds to run and is causing delays in our application. I've tried indexing the tables and adjusting the query structure, but it's still slow. Are there any other optimization techniques I can use to speed up the query?

Thank you.

```
SELECT
    orders.order_id,
    orders.order_date,
    customers.customer_name,
    products.product_name,
    order_details.quantity,
    order_details.unit_price
FROM
    orders
JOIN
    customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
JOIN
    order_details ON orders.order_id = order_details.order_id
JOIN
    products ON order_details.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE
    orders.order_date >= '2022-01-01'
    AND products.category = 'Electronics'
ORDER BY
    orders.order_date DESC;
```

ERROR: Query timeout expired. The query took more than 30 seconds to execute.

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

Comment: 1) Please copy the result of the explain into the question. 2) Please describe what indexes you have  defined on your impacted tables.

Comment: order_date >= '2022-01-01' : a DATE stored as a string? First suspect...

Comment: please edit your question to add (as text, not images) ouptut of `explain select...rest of your query` and of `show create table yourtablename` for all the tables used in the query; this is the minimum information needed to get good answers to optimization questions

Comment: @p3consulting, That's not a problem. Date literals are strings. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: You likely have an index on order.order_date. I'd try breaking this query into 2 parts. First part would query for recent orders and save in a temp table. Then use the temp table instead of the orders table in the 2nd query.

Comment: @BillKarwin: a date literal expression would be order_date >= DATE'2022-01-01'.

Comment: @p3consulting, That syntax is not needed in MySQL. A quoted string that contains a date is automatically cast to a date value when it is compared to a date. Try it!

Comment: @BartMcEndree - splitting one query into 2 rarely helps performance.

Comment: Please post the TEXT information requested by ysth on 2023 11 29 at 18:27 for meaningful assistance.

Answer (score 0):

These composite indexes may help:

```
orders:  INDEX(order_date, customer_id,  order_id)
customers:  INDEX(customer_id,  customer_name)
products:  INDEX(category, product_id,  product_name)
```

If not, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table so we can di deeper.

(And, I agree that `orders.order_date >= '2022-01-01'` is fine.)